# Ajax check if can access to https page

Tags: ajax, https, certificate

I have a webpage with a link to an https one, but before I go to that one, I want to check if it is possible to access it, I mean if user have the certificate installed, I use this function:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?=$url ?>",
        dataType: 'script',
        success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
            //alert(request + " : " status);
            window.location.replace("<?=$url ?>");
        },
        error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("ERROR");
            $('#cert').html('You dont have the certificate');
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#cert').html('You dont have the certificate')
    }, 5000);


</script>
```

The problem is that it works in firefox and safari, but explorer and chrome returns allways success and then I get the "Continue without the certificate" page that is what I want to avoid.

How can I know it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going from http to https in that Ajax call? Surprised it works at all with the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) since it is a different protocol.

Comment: Yes, I'm going from http to https and yes, it works in firefox: https://www.calldetenes.cat/?p=T1&id=215190985&col=009966

Anyway, what I want to know if the user can access the https page or not, is there any other way to know this?

Comment: You can not go from http to https. Read the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)